# Is there any way to do custom action while leaving the SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, communication-site

I have a scenario, I need to get feedback from the user who is leaving the SharePoint site.

Is there any way to achieve this kind of functionality? Please share any reference for this functionality.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: can you please elaborate as to what you are trying to accomplish and why you are seeking this route?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, there is no out of the box way to know when user is leaving the SharePoint site.

Comment: This post was tagged #SpFx,so I don’t think he is limiting his options to just OOB solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using OOB page comments to obtain user feedback. There is currently no such way to capture users who leave the site in a timely manner.

[image]